How to separate lines under same curve object?
I have created these lines by watching a youtube video. But now I want to separate each of these lines into individual lines.
How can I do that?


If they're not connected, you can in edit mode press P and select "by loose parts", each line will become its own object.
If they're connected, thogh, you will need to split first and then separate.
